Role of mortification and ascetism in buddhism
I am recently observing the effects of "asceticism" or in my case, simply reducing food/taste related pleasures. I know the Middle Way in Buddhism advocates avoiding the both the extremes of asceticism and indulgence in sense pleasures. However, I find that in contemporary Western society, there is a significant lean towards sense pleasures and material comforts.
Given the prevalence of indulgence in things like food, luxury, entertainment, and other sensual pleasures, I’m curious about the role of asceticism for lay practitioners today.

How should lay practitioners approach ascetic practices in the context of modern Western society?
Is there a recommended balance between asceticism and engaging with the comforts of modern life?
What specific ascetic practices can be beneficial for lay practitioners to help reduce attachment to sensual pleasures and support their spiritual growth?

Any answers/opinions are appreciated. Thanks!

The Dhammapada says,

Long-suffering patience is the supreme ascetic practice. Nirvana is supreme, say the Buddhas. He is certainly not an ascetic who hurts others, and nor is he a man of religion who causes suffering to others.
 
Not to speak harshly and not to harm others, self restraint in accordance with the rules of the Order, moderation in food, a secluded dwelling, and the cultivation of the higher levels of consciousness - this is the teaching of the Buddhas.
 
There is no satisfying the senses, not even with a shower of money. "The senses are of slight pleasure and really suffering." When a wise man has realised this, he takes no pleasure, as a disciple of the Buddhas, even in the pleasures of heaven. Instead he takes pleasure in the elimination of craving.

For craving of sense objects, teachers say when you train yourself to see that things are impermanent, and therefore stressful and unsatisfactory, and not worthy of being clung to, then letting go starts to happen automatically. It's disenchantment rather than willpower. It would be like how you're no longer interested in playing with the same toys you did as a little kid.
A Buddhist ascetic practice in the old days was to go to a charnel ground where human corpses were strewn about in various stages of decay, and wild animals scavenged and fought over them. Ajahn Mahaboowa likened your own living body to a charnel ground. It goes into more detail here: https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/thai/boowa/straight.html#radiant
So you could liken the cemetery contemplations or recollection of foulness of the body to an ascetic practice. It may not be physically painful or dangerous, you won't get attacked by wild dogs just thinking about it, but it is a denial of the usual desire for the body, your own and others'. It's also meant to result in disenchantment.

It might help to remember that it's not the case that only monks can follow the advice given to monks in the Pali Canon. If you want to give any of the ascetic practices a try it's totally up to you. Laypeople in Asia often stay in monasteries, which can mean eating only one meal a day at one sitting and sometimes even staying up all night meditating. You're also free to adapt things creatively to your lifestyle at home. The main set of extra practices for laypeople is the eight precepts:

Not killing
Not stealing
Not having sex (at all)
Not lying
Not taking alcohol or other intoxicants that make you careless
Not eating after noon
Not watching shows, not adorning yourself with jewellery, perfumes or make-up.
Not using high beds or chairs.

These might help challenge some of your cravings. Also, getting over what modern society thinks about how you're living your life differently is one of the beneficial challenges of taking these precepts on. We can be confident they've never been fashionable in any society outside of the society of noble disciples, and that's the society whose opinions you want to care about most.
The Buddha says laypeople should take these on the uposatha, or you could just do them on any day that's convenient once a week. He also says they lead to extremely great benefit. See:
AN 3.71
AN 10.46

Following are ways for integrating Buddhist practices in daily modern life:

Take up ascetic practices without hurting yourself or others.
Reduce worldly possessions.
Practice mindful eating.
Get engaged with local Buddhist community(Sangha)
Prioritise time for mediation.
Follow five percepts.

Meditation is very important. Have deep faith in the teachings of Buddha.
